# iptables user-defined chain not working

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, redhat

I am testing rate limiting to outbound IP's using iptables with user defined chains. So far I have only been able to get this to work with inbound traffic to my server. I cant seem to rate limit outbound. I am wanting to limit all udp traffic to a certain IP from my server to 1 packet per second. Here are the rules I ran:

```
#iptables -N udp-flood
#iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.10.100/32 -p udp -j udp-flood
#iptables -A udp-flood -d 192.168.10.100/32 -p udp -m limit --limit 1/s -j RETURN
#iptables -A udp-flood -j DROP
```

Here are the relavent parts of iptables --list:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination             
udp-flood  udp  --  anywhere             192.168.10.100    

Chain udp-flood (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.10.100      limit:   avg 1/sec burst 5 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And here is my iptables file:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6005:743055]
:udp-flood - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33434:33523 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.10.100/32 -p udp -j udp-flood
-A udp-flood -d 192.168.10.100/32 -p udp -m limit --limit 1/sec -j   RETURN
-A udp-flood -j DROP
COMMIT
```

I can confirm the packets are hitting the default output chains "accept" BUT...Shouldn't it hit the first output rule which then jumps it over to my user defined chain which will then rate limit out and drop everything else? What am I missing here?

My version of iptables is 1.4.7 on RHEL 6.7

Comment: How often is the OUTPUT rule being matched? Have you looked at `iptables -nL OUTPUT` and `iptables -nL udp-flood`?

Comment: Efficiency note here: if you're already matching `-d 192.168.10.100/32` in the `OUTPUT` chain and sending just that traffic via the `udp-flood` chain, then you don't need to match that destination again there, as that will always match.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek nothing is matching but I figured out what the problem was. I am stress testing my DNS server and it does not like the tool I am using to craft packets. So instead of running it directly from the DNS server to initiate outbound I am running it from a client. Now all queries that are forwarded out DO hit the udp-flood chain and are getting limited and/or dropped.